# exchange server 2010 transport rules for domain extension

Tags: exchange-2010

I am brand new to exchange server 2010 and want to set up some transport rules. (using .plc.uk ) domain extension as an example.  (I also put this on superuser forum a week ago but no help so far)

• E-Mail will with keyword “PROTECT:” in subject message must be sent to .plc.uk E-Mail Addresses. CC,BCC sent to .plc.uk E-Mail Addresses.

• E-Mail from .plc.uk will only be allowed to be received by certain personnel, I have a list Tom Dick and Harry no one else other than these are allowed.

• Remote devices will not be allowed to download attachments for mail with keyword “PROTECT:” in subject E-Mails. They will be using Outlook Web App(OWA) or Outlook Anywhere

Are all three rules possible? or would I need to use message classification?

Could someone please help with Powershell cmdlet

```
New-TransportRule -Name "PROTECT_TO_PLC" –  ?????

New-TransportRule -Name "PLC_TO_AUTHLIST" –  ?????

New-TransportRule -Name "PROTECT_NOT_TO_RD" –  ?????
```

Comment: Hub Transport rules don't affect OMA <-> Client Access, so #3 is out. The others should be possible, but you may have to use classifications. There's no way to say `if message is NOT for {people}`, at least not directly. You can set policies for OMA devices, including encryption requirements; that may solve #3 for you (it doesn't keep select e-mails off the device, but can keep the devices secure)

Comment: So to clarify you would suggest a white list (group) for people that can receive a .plc.uk message.

Comment: If you read your first one closely, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st One (didn't test):

`New-TransportRule -Name "FW_PROTECT" -SubjectContainsWords "PROTECT:" -CopyTo "cc@plk.uk" -BlindCopyTo "bcc@plk.uk" -Enabled $true`

2nd One (didn't test):

`New-TransportRule -Name "PLC_TO_AUTHLIST" -FromAddressContainsWords "plc.uk"
-RejectMessageReasonText "You can't send this message." -RejectMessageEnhancedStatusCode: "5.7.1" -ExceptIfSentToMemberOf: "GroupOfAllowedUsers@domain.com" -Enabled $true`

The ExceptIfSentToMemberOf is a distribution list of people that are allowed to receive the email.

3rd One is not possible IMO.

Comment: E-Mail will with keyword “PROTECT:” in subject message must be sent only to .plc.uk E-Mail Addresses. Even if the the addresses are in the CC,BCC addresses fields. So the to email address must end in .plc.uk nothing else.

Comment: So these messages originate from the same plc.uk Exchange server, and you want these messages to reject to any non-plc.uk address?

Comment: The exchange server is not plc.uk, but if a user send a message from the within the exchange server with the word PROTECT: in the subject message then it must send it to a PLC.Uk address.

Comment: OK, I added the first rule.  Let me know if this doesn't fully answer your question.